# update in mysql need good statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in sql. I am having writting query based on data

How can I write query to update row; I want to follow this format;

```
UPDATE `reports_attributes` 
  (`ConID`,`CheckServices`,`Attribute1`,`Attribute2`,`Attribute3`,`Attribute4`,`Attribute5`,`Attribute6`,`Attribute7`,`Attribute8`) 
VALUES ('78','Execute Summary','criminality','color1','education','color5','employment_check_2','color7','report_status','color9')  
WHERE ConID=78 AND ReportType='interim_report'
```

Comment: what's wrong with your query ?

Comment: You shouldn't quote numbers by the way, the `ConID` '78' should be just 78

Comment: @Chief17 won't have any effect - mysql just coerces types to match the column definition.

Comment: @AD7six yeah, I know, but its good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Statement syntax is different from Insert.

```
UPDATE reports_attributes 
 Set 
 ConID='78',
 CheckServices='Execute Summary',
 Attribute1='criminality',
 Attribute2='color1',
 Attribute3='education',
 Attribute4='color5',
 Attribute5='employment_check_2',
 Attribute6='color7',
 Attribute7='report_status',
 Attribute8='color9'
WHERE ConID=78 AND ReportType='interim_report'
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for an UPDATE statement is

```
UPDATE reports_attributes
    SET ConID = 78,
        CheckServices = xxx, 
        .
        .
        n
WHERE ConID=78 AND ReportType='interim_report'
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in the question does not match the [syntax of an update statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

An example of a valid update statement is:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET
    foo = "bar"
WHERE
    id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE reports_attributes 
SET ConID='78', 
    CheckServices='Execute Summary' ,
    Attribute1='criminality', 
    Attribute2='color1', 
    Attribute3='education', 
    Attribute4='color5',
    Attribute5='employment_check_2',
    Attribute6='color7', 
    Attribute7='report_status', 
    Attribute8='color9' 
WHERE ConID=78 
      AND ReportType='interim_report'
```